# how to access the window of the html page in the iframe of another html page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

My question is simple, suppose i have a html file like this named goal.html:

```
<html>
.
.
.
<body>
...
<iframe id="main_display" src="../pages/main.html" width=300 height=300><iframe> 
.
.
.
```

and now i wrote a line of javascript in `main.html` like `window.a ="a"`

now my question is how can i get the value of `window.a` when i am in `goal.html`

after searching something and spending some time in google developing tool, i founded something relevant  it was `iframe.contentWindow` it returns an object but when i try to open(i mean to expand) it, it shows me an error:

```
Uncaught [object DOMException]
```

So how do i do this thing?

Comment: Tried contentWindow.document or contentDocument? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1452885/1998238

Comment: it gave me an error: `Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

Comment: If `contentWindow` doesn't work for you, try this: `var myFrame = document.getElementById("main_display").contentDocument;`

Comment: okey i got this all these things are not working on chrome but working very well on Firefox, but why?

Answer (score 0):

this should work on goat.html

```js
var childValue = document.getElementById("main_display").contentWindow.a;
```

Comment: gave me an error: `Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

Comment: the iframe url you are trying to access is on a different domain? due to [Same Origin Security Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), any browser blocks any script trying to access a frame that has another origin.

Answer (score 0):

It's weird that it doesn't work on Chrome. I suggest you try to put it in `.ready` and `.load` function.

```
$(function () {  
    $("#myiframe").load(function () {                        
        frames["myframe"].document.body.innerHTML = htmlValue;
    });
});
```

For more detail, take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199797/why-is-iframe-contentwindow-null).